# How to make Gnome 3 to restore application's window geometry?

Tags: gnome

I'd like to run GUI applications in the natural way, i.e. at the same geometry (size and position) as it was closed with. Current Gnome's behavior discourages a lot, as application's window appears with random geometry. 
Is there any plug-in, gnome-shell's hack or external application that could make that possible?

`wmctrl`/`devilspy` seems broken in last gnome-shell, even though these tools can't do exactly what I want.

Comment: _"Current Gnome's behavior discourages a lot, as application's window appears with random geometry."_ You mean the position ? Because the size part has always worked as expected for me (and I've been using gnome for about 15 years).

Comment: Are you gnome developer? Because if you are,  this "and I've been using gnome for about 15 years" isn't true. Gnome developers do not use gnome by them-self’s, because if they would, there were not so many blunders in Gnome. 
As for your question: Yes, I mean both the size part and the  position.